# Jquery Mobile Swipe events are not firing

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, swipe

Im using bootstrap and want to enable swipe gestures to an img carousel. Im registering on swipe handlers for the carousel items like:

```
    $(".carousel-inner").on( "swipe", ".item",  function () {
        console.log("swiped");
    });
```

Doing the same to register a click event handler works fine so the selection of elements seems to work. Also ($.mobile) returns true so jquery mobile is loaded properly.

I have my smartphone connected via usb cable and track the debugging via chrome developer tools. Click on the device triggers the click event but swipe wont do anything.

Any guesses why now swipe events are fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out jquery mobile was not loaded properly due to incompatible version of jquery core (version 3.1.1.). Changed the version to 1.11.1 and now everything is working fine.